# Making custom border html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make resizable sidebar with custom border using .png.
I have a sample of each side of border and corners, but I don't know how to make that my .png repeat horizontally on both sides and so vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I am assuming that you want the border to be flexible.

For CSS3 (IE9 and other modern browsers) you can use multiple backgrounds (for example, see http://jsfiddle.net/RCHtK/ ). Put a class on a `div` (like `fancyBorder`) and something like this CSS:

```
.fancyBorder {
    padding: 15px; /* this should probably be set at least to the width of your border image */
    background:
        url(topleftimage.png) top left no-repeat,
        url(toprightimage.png) top right no-repeat,
        url(bottomleftimage.png) bottom left no-repeat,
        url(bottomrightimage.png) bottom right no-repeat,
        url(top.png) top left repeat-x,
        url(bottom.png) bottom left repeat-x,
        url(left.png) top left repeat-y,
        url(right.png) top right repeat-y;         
}
```

**For earlier IE browsers** see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RCHtK/10/. This is tested in IE7 and 8 (should work in IE6 I believe). The code could be minimized with creative use of pseudo elements if you only wanted to support IE8. As you can see, a large number of non-semantic `div` elements are needed to do it. The relevant code is here:

HTML

```
<div class="fancyBorder">
<div class="fbInner">
    <div class="fbContent">
    Here is some sample text. <br />
    Here is some sample text. <br />
    Here is some sample text. <br />
    </div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="tl corner"></div>
    <div class="tr corner"></div>
    <div class="bl corner"></div>
    <div class="br corner"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fancyBorder {
    /* left side */
    background: url(leftimg.png) top left repeat-y;
}
.fbInner .fbContent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fbInner {
    padding: 15px; /* this should probably be set at least to the width of your border image */
    position: relative;
    /* right side */
    background:url(rightimage.png) top right repeat-y;
}

.fbInner div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
.fbInner .top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(topimage.png) top left repeat-x;
}
.fbInner .bottom {
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(bottomimage.png) bottom left repeat-x;
}
.fbInner .corner {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.fbInner .tl {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(topleftimage.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.fbInner .tr {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(toprightimage.png) top right no-repeat
}
.fbInner .bl {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(bottomleftimage.png) bottom left no-repeat;
}
.fbInner .br {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(bottomrightimage.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 [`border-image`](http://css-tricks.com/6883-understanding-border-image/)

Comment: Though I like the idea of the `border-image` property, its need for refinement in its implementation (and lack of IE support, even IE9) makes it less desirable for me than the multiple background solution. However, it certainly is an option that may work for Bosnian's needs.

Comment: If it were my choice, I'd use `border-image`, call it progressive enhancement and save 7 http requests. However, I found your solution very interesting!

Comment: Combining some images into sprites, I could reduce the http requests to 2 or 3 (depending on if top/bottom borders matched left/right borders), by putting all four corners into one image and the repeated images into 1 or 2 and setting background position.

Comment: In the interest of progress, however, I have decided your answer is at least worth my upvote as a possible solution (so much depends on the designer's goal and target audience).

Comment: http://demo15.cloudaccess.net/ I want to make block as it is on this joomla site.. left sidebar... and if you look at the code it will show seperatedleft border, bottom and top... how to make it like that..and flexible so that it expand as i put more content. :)

Comment: A decade later this is definitely the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to create border by image, just upload your image on [THIS WEBSITE](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fcss3-background%2Fborder.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B27%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22repeat%22%2C%22repeat%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D) and set value by given button: